# can someone help me make this formula work on an entire column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

im hoping that someone can help me to take a macro down an entire column.here is what i am trying to do.

the following table is in a worksheet called barcode. it is my master list. column E:E, is a helper column that has part numbers with countif numbers attach like so=:1,:2,:3, etc. i did this because i have multiple orders for part numbers that are due on different dates in the order report. in column c, there is a number of how many of a part has been ran. in column d, the number of parts that have been scrapped and would have to be ran again. i have highlighted a row to use as an example. in this case. part number ms-100 has a total of 1 part ran and zero scrapped.

[image]

the next sheet is my order report sheet. it displays what a customer has ordered of what part. the calculation that i want to have is: if ms-100:1 on the order report matches what is on the master list, then take the qty from the order report and subtract how many were ran, and add how many were scrapped. so for this case. if ms-100:1 =ms-100:1 then cell f8 =12-1+0.

[image]

my current code will do that, but it will only do the cells that i point them to and not the entire column. to make it easier to see if this code works or not, instead of changing the values of column f on the order report, i moved it to column l. the goal is to have the value change in f, but for now i was putting the value in l. as you can see, in L7, it says no order. i hope this clarifies what i am trying to accomplish. thank you very much. here is the code that i have so far. i was attempting to use for each cell but it doesnt seem to be working.

```
Sub FIND_MATCHES()

Dim sh1 As Worksheet

Dim sh4 As Worksheet

Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BARCODE")

Set sh4 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ORDER REPORT")
Dim CELL As Range
Dim LASTROW As Long
Dim R As Long
Dim c As Range
    Set c = sh4.Range("L:L")


    LASTROW = sh4.CELLS(Rows.COUNT, 12).End(xlDown).Row
    'LASTROW = Range("F7:F" & Rows.COUNT).End(xlUp).Row

Dim COMPID As Range
    Set COMPID = sh1.Range("E:E").Find(What:=sh4.Range("N7").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LOOKAT:=xlWhole)
    'sh4.Range("L7:L" & LASTROW).Activate
    'sh4.Range("L7:L" & LASTROW).Select
For Each CELL In c
If COMPID Is Nothing Then
    sh4.Range("L7").Value = "NO ORDER"
    Else
    'TEST CELL'sh4.Range("L7").Value = COMPID.Offset(, -2).Value
    sh4.Range("L7").Value = sh4.Range("F7").Value - COMPID.Offset(0, -2).Value + COMPID.Offset(0, -1).Value
    'Range("L7:L" & LASTROW).Select
   ' Range("L8").Select
    Exit For
End If

Next CELL

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution myself. the below code is what i used. I thought i would share it just in case someone else had the same issue.

```html
 Sub FIND_MATCHES()

Dim barcode As Worksheet
Dim order As Worksheet
    Set barcode = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("BARCODE")
    Set order = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ORDER REPORT")
Dim LASTROW As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim X As Integer
    X = 1
Dim finalrow As String
    finalrow = order.cells(Rows.COUNT, 12).End(xlUp).Row
Dim location As Range
    Set location = barcode.cells.Item(X, "E")
Dim HELPER As String
Dim NUMROWS As String
        
        NUMROWS = order.cells(Rows.COUNT, 14).End(xlUp).Row
        HELPER = barcode.cells.Item(X, "E").Value
        LASTROW = order.cells(Rows.COUNT, 14).End(xlUp).Row
           
 Dim ENDROW As String
        ENDROW = order.cells(Rows.COUNT, 4).End(xlUp).Row
            For X = 1 To ENDROW
                
                    For c = 7 To NUMROWS
                            If order.cells(c, 14).Value = barcode.cells.Item(X, "E").Value Then
                                order.cells(c, 12).Value = order.cells(c, 6).Value - barcode.cells.Item(X, "E").OFFSET(0, -2).Value + barcode.cells.Item(X, "E").OFFSET(0, -1).Value
                            Else
                                 ActiveCell.OFFSET(1, 0).Select
                                 End If
                    Next c
           Next X
          order.Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```